Bound for norm of projection onto $k$-dimensional subspace in terms of projections onto basis vectors
Let $V$ a finite-dimensional vector space with inner product $\langle, \rangle$.
Let $v_1,\dots,v_k \in V$ linearly independent vectors of unit length.
Let $p_i:V \rightarrow \text{span}(v_i)$ defined by $p_i(w):=\langle v_i,w \rangle v_i$ be the projection onto the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $v_i$ for $i \in \{1,\dots,k\}$.
Let $p:V \rightarrow \text{span}(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ be the orthogonal projection onto the $k$-dimensional subspace spanned by $v_1,\dots,v_k$.

Question:
is there an upper bound for $|p(w)|$ in terms of $p_i(w)$ and products/volumes computed involving $v_1,\dots,v_k$?
Here, $|\cdot |=\sqrt{\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle}$.

If $v_1,\dots,v_k$ are pairwise orthonormal, then $|p(w)|^2=\sum_{i=1}^k |p_i(w)|^2$.
In the case of $k=2$ and $v_1,v_2$ having unit length (but not necessarily being orthogonal), I would expect something like $|p(w)| \leq \frac{1}{1+\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle}(|p_1(w)|+|p_2(w)|)$ to hold, but I wasn't able to show that.
(The fraction can attain a large value if $\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle$ is close to $-1$, but by the assumption that $v_1,v_2$ be linearly dependent, it is always well defined.)
If $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A=(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ denotes the matrix consisting of the column vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$ written next to each other, then $p=AA^+$, where $A^+$ denotes the pseudo-inverse of $A$.
If one could get an upper bound for the norm of $A^+ w$ in terms of $p_i(w)$ and products/volumes computed involving $v_1,\dots,v_k$, that would solve the problem, but I don't know if that's possible.

If I understand right, $|p(w)| \leq \prod_{i=1}^{k} |p_i(w)|,|v_i|$ (the volume of the image is no greater than the product of the side lengths of the images). Are you seeking a sharper estimate in terms of the angles between the image vectors?

I don't mind sharpness. Any estimate with only $|p_i(w)$ and $|v_i|$ on the right would be great if it's somewhat explicit (which yours certainly is!). But it seems that estimate is not quite right the way it's written. $p_i(w)$ can be zero without $p(w)$ being zero, which would contradict your inequality. E.g.: $v_1=(1,0)$, $v_2=(0,1)$, $w=(1,0) \Rightarrow p(w)=(1,0)$, $\prod |p_i(w)| \cdot |v_i|=(1 \cdot 1)(0 \cdot 1)=0$.

Ah, I did misunderstand: You're bounding the length of a vector, not the $k$-dimensional volume of a parallelipiped. <> The best approach I see (without referring to angles between image vectors) is to use the triangle inequality. (Tangential question: Are the $v_i$ unit vectors? This doesn't appear to be mentioned, except implicitly in the projection formula. :)

I see. For simplicity I assumed that the $v_i$ are unit length vectors (not necessarily orthogonal) and forgot to write that. I've added that to the question. I think the triangle inequality alone won't do it. Consider $v_1=(1,0), v_2=(-\sqrt{1-\epsilon},\sqrt{\epsilon})$ for small $\epsilon$. For $w=(0,1)$ we have $p(w)=w$ but $p_1(w)=0$ and $p_2(w)=(0,\epsilon)$, so $|p(w)| \leq |p_1(w)|+|p_2(w)|$ doesn't hold. Maybe this argument can be improved somehow?

To answer your question, I resort to the equivalence of all norms on a finite-dimensional vector space.

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$, and $p,q:V\to \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ are two norms on $V$, then there exist constants $m,M>0$ such that $$ mp(v)\leq q(v)\leq Mp(v),\qquad \forall v\in V.$$

Note that $q:V\to \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ given by
$$ w\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n |p_i(w)|$$
is a norm on $V$. Thus, there exists some $m>0$ such that
$$ p(w)\leq\frac1m q(w),\qquad \forall w\in V.$$

Thanks! Can you express $m$ in terms of products, volumes computed using $v_1,\dots,v_k$?
